# Qual a maneira correta de retirar a borda com CSS?

Tags: css

Para retirar bordas no CSS eu geralmente utilizo um dos dois valores:

```
.exemplo{
    border:0;
    /* ou */
    border:none;
}
```

O engraçado é que ambos funcionam, e isso acontece com outras propriedades como `outline`, mas qual das duas propriedades seria o *correto* de se usar neste caso? Ou melhor, existe um "correto" (semanticamente falando) ou isso não faz diferença?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja na seção 8.5.3 desta página da W3C (órgão regulamentador) disponível neste link:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border

Segundo a mesma `none` é a propriedade que define que o elemento não terá borda e será computado com expessura 0.

Ambos estão corretos, mas se sua intenção é não ter nenhuma borda utilize 'none' que demonstra melhor suas intenções de código (semântica).

Answer (score 2):

Qualquer um dos dois vale.

De acordo com as [especificações](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border), você utiliza um **ou** o outro.

```
Value:      [ <border-width> || <border-style> || <'border-top-color'> ] | inherit
```

`Size: 0` ou `Style: none`, ambos são considerados corretos e podem ser utilizados sozinhos

A não ser que você esteja preocupado com o tamanho do css e consequentemente o desempenho, aí acaba valendo mais a pena *(por pouco, muito pouco, quase nada)* utilizar o 0, embora a diferença não seja notada tão cedo.

Answer (score 2):

Os dois estão corretos, se você definir 0 ou none da no mesmo.